# Cannot visualize Winamp Plug-in - Visualize Her (This gorgeous high-poly 3-D hottie)

Tags: windows-7, winamp

I saw in YouTube a nice Winamp plug-in and would like to use in my computer. So I downloaded it here: http://info2.winamp.com/plugins/details/146758

I installed, but when I try to visualize a pop-up informs only (Application Error. The visualizer will now exit. / Title: "Mojo Master").

In settings > preferences > plug-ins > visualizer > mojo master visualizer:

- There isn't any configurations
- In first time I tried to start, it shows a pop-up informing to verify something about DirectX or to restart OS. After the first time, all other times the pop-up said above appears

The Winamp version is 5.61.

The computer is a notebook with Windows 7 and last Windows updates, including DirectX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found a sort of DirectX tweakers (http://www.mdgx.com/newtip18.htm#DXTWK:) and them helped me again.

This time I used DXTEST: http://www.mdgx.com/dx.htm#TST

After installed, shortcut is saved to start menu > accessories

In Direc3D 9, I uncheck "Software Only".

Side effects: MSCV 2010 will show some display issues, as related in [Display issue in "newer" Microsoft programs in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/309803/display-issue-in-newer-microsoft-programs-in-windows-7/311002#311002) , but to solve it I only have to check that option again.